# PHP - Calculate balance with previous value

Tags: php

I am trying make code in php with mysql database, and i want to calculate balance with stored value and new inputed value. for example i have database like this:

```
id  |  debit  | credit | balance
----+---------+--------+--------
 1  |   70000 |      0 |  70000
 2  |       0 |  44000 |  26000
 3  |   45000 |  15000 |  56000
 4  |       0 |  32000 |  24000
 5  |       0 |  10000 |  14000
 6  |   28000 |      0 |  42000
```

the formula is `balance = old_balance + new_inputed_debit - new_inputed_credit`
so if i inputed new value like this in html form:

> debit = 30000
>   credit = 5000

so the script will sum this when i click input button `balance = 42000 + 30000 - 5000`
And the database will become like this:

```
id  |  debit  | credit | balance
----+---------+--------+--------
 1  |   70000 |      0 |  70000
 2  |       0 |  44000 |  26000
 3  |   45000 |  15000 |  56000
 4  |       0 |  32000 |  24000
 5  |       0 |  10000 |  14000
 6  |   28000 |      0 |  42000
 7  |   30000 |   5000 |  67000 <-- New Submited Value
```

this is my php script:

```
<?php
    require('db2.php');
    // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $debit = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['debit']);
        $credit = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['credit']);
        $balance = //old_balance + new_inputed_debit - new_inputed_credit
        $query = "INSERT into `balance` (debit, credit, balance,) VALUES ('$debit','$credit', '$balance')";
        if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
            echo "<div class='form'><h3>Inputed Success</h3><br/><a href='Input.php'>Input again</a></div> or <a href='index.php'>back</a>";
        }else{
        }
    }
?>
```

And this is my html code:

```
<form name="input_data" action="" method="post"><br />
<label style="font-size:16px;">Debit :</label>
<input type="text" name="debit" placeholder="Ex: 90000" style="margin-left:3px; width:80% !important;" required /><br />
<label style="font-size:16px;">Credit :</label>
<input type="text" name="credit" placeholder="Ex: 90000" style="margin-left:3px; width:80% !important;" required /><br />
<span style="float:right;"><input type="reset" name="reset" value="RESET" style="margin-right:8px;" /> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="INPUT" style="margin-right:8px;" /></span>
</form>
```

Is anyone can help me to create the php script? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

initialize balance with 0 in case you have no rows in table. after that get last row from table and get old_balance from that row. just place this script after $credit = .... line. you will get old_balance from last row or 0 if there will be no rows.

```
$old_balance = 0;
$sql = "select max(id), balance from balance_table";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $old_balance = $row["balance"];
}
```

Comment: getting error in Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in balance.php

Comment: change your table name or column name from 'balance' to any other name and try to execute select query in phpmyadmin to  check if it returns any data.

Comment: This error comes when your query does not execute successfully. so do as per above comment

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be usefull for you :)

```
$old_balance = 0;
$sql = "select max(id), balance from balance";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $old_balance = $row["balance"];
}
```